# How do I measure CPU, memory and disk usage during a build?

Tags: linux, build, makefile, build-process

I'm trying to improve my build times and want to have some feedback in place to measure where my problems are.

I'm using GNU Make on a Linux CentOS system to build the Linux kernel along with some application code. I can run Make with 'time' to get an overall time for the complete build, but that doesn't tell me where the bottlenecks are.

I used -j with Make to run it on multiple cores on my build machine, but I ran top during the build and noticed the CPU cores were often idle.

Any suggestions for the best way to measure disk and memory usage during the build?

Anything else I should be measuring?

No preference on text-based or GUI - whatever gives me some data I can use.

Comment: This might interest you: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/156569/8977

Comment: @bitmask thanks, that was useful. I'll start running some experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real time measurement I use tex-based htop from [third-party](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/htop/) repositories. It is like top but better, it shows graphically cpu (all cpu's separately), ram load.